# Automapper ninject dependencies

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, automapper

I have a problem with the Automapper on my website and I can't find a solution.
I've created a class called AutoMapperProfile where I'd like to put all my Maps

```
public class AutoMapperProfile: Profile
{
    private readonly IConfiguration _mapper;

    public AutoMapperProfile(IConfiguration mapper)
    {
        _mapper = mapper;
    }

    protected override void Configure()
    {
        base.Configure();

        _mapper.CreateMap<SlideDTO, Slide>();
        _mapper.CreateMap<Slide, SlideDTO>();
    }
}
```

For DI purposes I'm using Ninject, so I've added the following bindings in NinjectWebCommon:

```
kernel.Bind<IMappingEngine>().ToMethod(ctx => Mapper.Engine);
kernel.Bind<IConfigurationProvider>().ToMethod(x => Mapper.Engine.ConfigurationProvider);
```

The controller looks like this:

```
private readonly ISlideRepository slideRepository;
    private readonly IMappingEngine mappingEngine;

    public HomeController(
        ISlideRepository slideRepository,
        IMappingEngine mappingEngine)
    {
        this.slideRepository = slideRepository;
        this.mappingEngine = mappingEngine;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var model = new IndexViewModel();
        var slide = slideRepository.GetSlide();
        model.Slide = mappingEngine.Map<SlideDTO, Slide>(slide);

        return View(model);
    }
```

When I map from SlideDTO to Slide I get the following error:

```
Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping.
```

So my best guess is that I didn't do the binds correctly so that Automapper can see my maps, but I'm not sure how can I fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to inject `IConfiguration` into `AutoMapperProfile`, it already inherits a `CreateMap` method from `Profile`.

Make sure that `AutoMapperProfile` has a parameterless constructor  like this:

```
public class AutoMapperProfile : Profile
{
    protected override void Configure()
    {
        this.CreateMap<SlideDTO, Slide>();
        this.CreateMap<Slide, SlideDTO>();
    }
}
```

And then you need to make sure that AutoMapper knows about this profile, here is how you can do it:

```
Mapper.Engine.ConfigurationProvider.AddProfile<AutoMapperProfile>();
```

Please note that you can invoke the `AddProfile` method on any `IConfigurationProvider` (if you decide not to use the global `ConfigurationProvider` and `Engine`).

Comment: in which file we have to add line `Mapper.Engine.ConfigurationProvider.AddProfile<AutoMapperProfile>();
` ?